# how can i solve this contract problem? only 2 functions

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, solidity, smartcontracts, cryptojs

I need a contract that receives the function to add the score to the score that already exists in the associated wallet if present or otherwise creates a new one (score and address) after which I need a function that retrieves all the addresses with their scores . if possible a function that already sends you the ranking, otherwise just all the addresses with their scores are fine

```
contract ScoreTracker {
    mapping(address => uint) public scores;

    function addScore(address _wallet, uint _score) public {
        if (scores[_wallet] == 0) {
            scores[_wallet] = _score;
        } else {
            scores[_wallet] += _score;
        }
    }

    function getScore(address _wallet) public view returns (uint) {
        return scores[_wallet];
    }
}   

function getAllScores() public view returns (address[] memory, uint256[] memory) {
    address[] memory addresses = new address[](scores.length);
    uint256[] memory scoresList = new uint256[](scores.length);
    uint256 counter = 0;
    for (address; scores) {
        addresses[counter] = a;
        scoresList[counter] = scores[a];
        counter++;
    }
    return (addresses, scoresList);
}
```

i had try my best. but dont know how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

You need a few things.

Solidity cannot enumerate mappings so you need to create a mapping of the wallets to the index.  You also need to increment this by one, so you can tell whether a wallet has been added.

```
mapping(address => uint) public walletIndexIncrementedMap;
WalletScores[] scores;

struct WalletScores {
    adddress wallet;
    uint256 score;
}


function getOrAddWalletScore(address _wallet, uint256 score) public {
    uint256 incrementedIndex = walletIndexIncrementedMap[_wallet];
    if(0 == incrementedIndex) {
        WalletScore storage walletScore = scores.push();
        incrementedIndex = scores.length;
        walletIndexIncrementedMap[_wallet] = incrementedIndex;
        walletScore.wallet = _wallet;
        walletScore.score = score;
        return;
    }
    WalletScore storage walletScore = scores[incrementedIndex - 1];
    walletScore.score += score;
}

function getAllScores() public returns (WalletScores[] memory walletScores) 
{
   return scores;
}
```